# Disable all debugger statements in JS

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm injecting a `<script>` tag into a local version of a site's DOM, and it has some really random and annoying `debugger;` statements in other `<script>` tags. I was wondering if it's possible to just rip all these out? I'd do a text replace on the DOM but there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: If it's your code then just delete all the debuggers. If you are debugging in chrome, if you hold click on the pause/play button on the script tab then you'll see an option to continue the execution without stopping. Maybe that can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to debugger » Breakpoints » right click on it » Deactivate breakpoints

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! I'll accept it ASAP, can't right now due to internet issues

Comment: @RhysO ... Vote Up

Answer (score 9):

In Chrome there is an option to disable all breakpoints.  Obviously this only affects your own browser, but might be enough?

Ctrl+F8

[image: Deactivate breakpoints]